# SQL Question: INNER JOIN(SELF JOIN) eliminates duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Data Table 
[image]

Question: List the names of all the supervisors in alphabetical order.  If the supervisor has more than one staff, his name should appear only once.

My input and output: 
[image]

Expected Output: 
[image]

Absolute beginner in SQL and new to stackoverflow, help rendered will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`

Comment: `select distinct supervisorname from ...`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM staff s where exists(select 1 from staff x where x.supervisor_id = s.id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to find out the supervisors first by using a cte or temptable, then use it to select the names like:

```
;with cte as ( --supervisors
   select distinct s1.Id
   from Staff s1
   inner join Staff s2 on s1.Id=s2.SupervisorId
)
select s.Name
from Staff s
inner join cte on s.Id = cte.Id
order by s.Name
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do:

```
select s.*
from staff s
where exists (select 1 from staff s2 where s.staffId = s2.supervisorid);
```

That is, select all staff who are supervisors.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this query:

```
SELECT MAX(Staff.Name) As SupervisorName
FROM Staff INNER JOIN Staff Sup 
ON  Staff.SupervisorID = Sup.StaffID
GROUP BY Staff.Name
ORDER BY Staff.Name ASC
```